# Comparison of Two MYSQL TIMESTAMP Columns not providing correct results

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables **client** and **followup**. I need to select based on following conditions.

If subscriber_id in table client t1 **NOT IN** followup table t2 and t1.paid_amount = 0 AND t1.update_balance > 200

OR

If subscriber_id **IS IN** table followup t2 and and t1.paid_amount = 0 AND t1.update_balance > 200 **AND ALSO** if t1.update_time GREATER THAN t2.update_time.
Both the update_time in both tables are in MYSQL **TIMESTAMP** Format.

My current query is as follows:

```
SELECT t1.id,t1.subscriber_id,t1.paid_amount,t1.update_balance
FROM client AS t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN followup AS t2 ON t1.subscriber_id = t2.subscriber_id
WHERE (t2.subscriber_id IS NULL AND t1.paid_amount = 0 AND t1.update_balance > 200) OR (t2.subscriber_id IS NOT NULL AND t1.paid_amount = 0 AND t1.update_balance > 200 AND 't1.update_time'> 't2.update_time')
```

But the **data is not selected** if  t1.update_time **> THAN** t2.update_time..

```
Client Table:
-------------------------------------------------------------------
id   subscriber_id  paid_amount    update_balance  update_time
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1     AB4567            0              500      2020-07-12 18:22:24
2.    AB4568            0              300      2020-07-15 17:22:24
--------------------------------------------------------------------

Followup Table
------------------------------------------------------------------
id   subscriber_id  feedback  update_time
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1.   AB4567          paid      2020-07-12 17:22:24 
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

1. If subscriber_id **NOT IN** table 2 - Display ROW
2. If subscriber_id **IN** table 2 - Display **if t1.update_time > t2.update_time**

Requesting Help from Mysql Experts..

Comment: provide sample data with your desired output

Comment: It would probably be better to write two queries, and combine them with `UNION`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the whole problem, but

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP('t1.update_time'> 't2.update_time')
```

should be

```
t1.update_time > t2.update_time
```

First, there's no need to use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` when comparing, you can just compare the dates directly.

Second, you shouldn't quote the column names. That makes them string literals. See [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks).

Third, if you do use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP`, you need to call it separately on each column, e.g.

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t1.update_time) > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t2.update_time)
```

Your code was comparing the strings, which evaluates to `TRUE`, which is `1`, so it was evaluating
`UNIX_TIMESTAMP(1)`

To make the whole query work, split it up into two queries that you combine with `UNION`.

```
SELECT t1.id,t1.subscriber_id,t1.paid_amount,t1.update_balance
FROM client AS t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN followup AS t2 ON t1.subscriber_id = t2.subscriber_id
WHERE t1.paid_amount = 0 AND t1.update_balance > 200
AND t2.subscriber_id IS NULL

UNION 

SELECT t1.id,t1.subscriber_id,t1.paid_amount,t1.update_balance
FROM client AS t1
INNER JOIN followup AS t2 ON t1.subscriber_id = t2.subscriber_id AND t1.update_time > t2.update_time
WHERE t1.paid_amount = 0 AND t1.update_balance > 200
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/q84yvef3Q3sEUAYuLXGFiA/1)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218289/discussion-on-answer-by-barmar-comparison-of-two-mysql-timestamp-columns-not-pro).